Is it possible to find and call a function by its decorator?
What I want to achieve:
I want to develop a core browser library for a given product. There are some parts where function implementations will differ based on a customization ( let's call them plugin functions ). I want to avoid having to manage these plugin functions inside the library code, I want to manage them in different code bases and only install them during CI/CD so I can include them in the bundle.
The app configuration tells the system which plugin function to choose, let's assume customer 1 is going for foo and customer 2 for bar. It would be nice if the core library gets a parameter to identify the correct function to be called.

What I've done so far:
During runtime I had no idea how to call an implementation without an "explicit" if-statement. I think the only way that might work is to use decorators. The configuration will contain a unique name so I might search for a given function.
I started with this decorator every plugin should use
function pluginFunc(name: string) {
  console.log(`plugin func '${name}'`);

  return function (
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) {
    console.log({ name, target, propertyKey, descriptor });
  };
}

export { pluginFunc };

And a custom plugin
import { pluginFunc } from "./pluginFunc";

@pluginFunc("foo")
function pluginOne() {
  console.log("hello from plugin 1");
}

export { pluginOne }

Now I want to test my approach in a simple index.ts file
/* async */ function callPlugin(name: string) {
  // find function by decorator and name and call it
}

callPlugin('foo');

Is it possible to find a function ( without importing it during build time! ) by a decorator pluginFunc and a given name?
If that's not possible what about the simpler approach to simply call a function by its name ( without importing it ) ?

"There are some parts where function implementations will differ based on a customization ( let's call them plugin functions )" - sounds like you're looking for a hook system

How many plugins can provide an implementation for a given name? One? More than one (if you allow bundling multiple plugins)? Can there be no implementation (if no pluging is loaded)?

@Bergi you might be right but the library or product must register them somewhere. I was looking for a way to autodetect them

@Bergi exactly 1, one plugin, one implementation. Yes, there can be no implementation ( empty application then... )

Why do you say "without importing it"? Having a mock module with lots of empty functions, then replacing that by the respective plugin file at deployment time, would be the simplest solution.

Keep it stupidly simple:
// index.ts
import hooks from './hooks.ts';
hooks.foo();

// hooks.ts
export default {
  foo() {}, // noop, or default implementation
};

// plugin.ts
import hooks from './hooks.ts';
hooks.foo = function pluginOne() {
  console.log("hello from plugin 1");
};

This is the basic pattern. You can of course make the hook registration more elaborate if you don't like the simple assignment, and use something like registerHook('foo', function pluginOne() { … }); or those fancy decorators. It is assumed that the plugin.ts is somehow loaded at startup - whether you do that with import './plugin.ts'; somewhere, a special plugin loader function, or through the environment or build process is up to you.

Thanks but now the plugin lives inside the library code :(

@baitendbidz No, why? You can place the plugin.ts file wherever you want. It can be a folder of plugin1.ts, plugin2.ts… files, it can be separate repositories. All you have to do is to bundle one (or none) of them into your deployed code somehow so that it gets run at startup.
